# What's the point of using the "cols" attribute of the <textarea> tag in HTML?

Tags: html

The "cols" attribute is required in valid HTML but I don't see the benefit of using it. Do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the client does not support CSS, it will still be able to see `<textarea>` with right width.

Comment: Are there clients that do not CSS and if the <textarea> requires a "cols" attribute, why the <input type="text"> does not?

Comment: Because it has other attributes: `<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="20">` See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Comment: Because it only makes sense for `text` and `password` types, and the `<input>` element is also used for `radio`, `checkbox`, `button`... Also remember the spec was made to officialize the behavior already common among existing browsers. It doesn't need to make perfect sense.

Comment: @Emanuil. Lynx does not support CSS for example. The HTML specification does not give any answers on your quiestion. It just says, "cols and rows are required". I think they are required as fallback if browser doesn't support CSS, or if user disabled it; it's reasonable. Also CSS width/height and cols/rows act differently.

Answer (score 1):

It determines how wide to render the element.

Comment: Yes, but you can do the same through CSS and do it much more precisely.

Comment: The spec predates common CSS support and use (and given a monospace font (the default), columns is usually a much easier way to get the precise width you want)

Answer (score 1):

When browsers and html parsing software looks at HTML it will be looking for a set of mandatory attributes on a tag. Such as every `<img>` tag needs an alt="" attribute.

So when running your site through a HTML validator you need to make sure the mandatory attributes are in place else validation will fail..

Secondly when a user is using assistive technologies, they tend to turn off CSS/Javascript altogether so making sure you have cols="" in there is important. Screan readers and such may not be able to parse your webpage properly if it can't find required attributes for your markup.

**Conclusion**: Theres a bigger picture than just tweaking some stylesheet info. Make sure you conform to spec. If you want to style things pretty make sure you have sensible fallback for non-css webpages.

Answer (score 0):

"cols" using for increase the width of textarea` in html.